# ubuntu 20.04 dgpu is always on

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, power-management, 20.04

I have installed ubuntu 20.04 on a msi prestige 15. This laptop has a nice feature, the led on the power button is orange when the discrete gpu is active, otherwise is white.

I have installed the proprietary driver and selected "intel (power saving mode)" in the prime profiles. This worked correctly with ubuntu 19.10: after selecting ubuntu in the grub menù the led turned white.
With ubuntu 20.04 the led often remains orange for several minutes or does not turn white at all. The dgpu is powered up even if is not used and the drain on the battery is very high.

This is the output of nvidia-smi:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

As it should be.

otuput of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9bca (rev 04)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 129c
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
```

I find this [post](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-5.5-dGPU-Sound-Bind-Power), it's a bug in the kernel 5.4?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: It doesn't look like the driver is properly installed. Is Secure Boot disabled in BIOS? What is the driver version?

Comment: I'm using the nvidia-driver-440, with the 435 there is the same problem

Comment: So is Secure Boot disabled?

Comment: Was it a fresh install of 20.04 or an upgrade from 19.10?

Comment: yes, secure boot si disabled and it was a fresh install

Comment: Then report a bug by running `ubuntu-bug nvidia prime`.

Comment: Can you post a bug link ?